General formula for reversing double integral bounds
The double integral over the region:
$$
R = \left\{ \left( x,\: y \right) : a \leqslant x \leqslant b,\: g\left( x \right) \leqslant y \leqslant h\left( x \right) \right\}
$$
is expressed as
$$
\iint_R f\left( x,\: y \right) \mathrm{d}A = \int_a^b \left[ \int_{g\left( x \right)}^{h\left( x \right)} f\left( x, \: y \right) \mathrm{d}y \right] \mathrm{d}x.
$$
By Fubini's theorem, any permutation of the order of integration is equivalent if the function $f$ is integrable.
Assuming $f$ is integrable, if $g$ and $h$ are invertible on the interval $a \leqslant x \leqslant b$, is it correct to say that in general, the reversed double integral has the form:
$$
\iint_R f\left( x, \: y \right) \mathrm{d}A = \int_{g\left( a \right)}^{h\left( b \right)} \left[ \int_{h^{-1}\left( y \right)}^{g^{-1}\left( y \right)} f\left( x, \: y \right) \mathrm{d}x \right] \mathrm{d}y.
$$
Would there be any other restrictions on the functions $g$ and $h$?
Thank you for your help.

Look up the following adjectives in relationship to changing order of integration and Fubini's theorem- simple, type I, type II & connected.

The area of the double integral with the reversed bounds differs from that of the first integral, which can be easily seen from the following figure; compare the two ranges $(a,b)$ and $\left (h^{-1}(g(a)),g^{-1}(h(b))\right).$


Thanks. This was basically how I arrived at the equation in my post. I guess a plot suffices.

I will award you the bounty as it's about to expire.

@LightninBolt74 Thank you!
